# NullPointerExceptions when initializing a RevoluteJointDef

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, andengine

I have started diving into more complex uses for AndEngine, as I was starting to get the hang of it, or so i thought. I have ran into a NPE that i cannot seem to figure out, so I would therefore be grateful for any assistance.

The class below represents a crude ragdoll/stickman, and the class itself registers all its textures, bodies, joints and whatnot with andengine. The mainActivity (which extends SimpleBaseGameActivity) then calls its constructor during initialization this way:

`this.skater = new Skater(this, mPhysicsWorld, new Vector2(startX, startY));`

I've trimmed away some code that is mostly repeating the same stuff for other joints and limbs, so only stuff for the ankle joint is included, as the wall-of-text is large enough as it is.

The NPE is thrown on this line towards the end of the constructor:

`this.jAnkle.initialize(bSkates, bLegs, new Vector2(stickmanPos.x, sSkates.getHeight()));`

```
public class Stickman {

        //////////////
        // Constructor

        public Stickman(Testgame game, PhysicsWorld engine, Vector2 stickmanPos) {

                this.game = game;
                this.engine = engine;
                this.stickmanPos = stickmanPos;    

                // Create textures
                textureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(game.getTextureManager(), 1024, 1024, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
                this.tSkates   = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(this.textureAtlas, this.game, "stickman_skates.png",   0, 0, 2, 1);
                this.tLegs   = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(this.textureAtlas, this.game, "stickman_legs.png",   0, 0, 2, 1);
                // --SNIPPED--

                // Create sprites
                this.sSkates   = new AnimatedSprite(stickmanPos.x,              stickmanPos.y, this.tSkates, game.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                this.sLegs   = new AnimatedSprite(stickmanPos.x + skatesToLegs, stickmanPos.y, this.tLegs,   game.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                // --SNIPPED--

                // Create body with sprites
                this.bSkates   = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(engine, sSkates,   BodyType.DynamicBody, game.FIX_SKATER);
                this.bLegs   = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(engine, sLegs,   BodyType.DynamicBody, game.FIX_SKATER);
                // --SNIPPED--         

                // Register bodies with Box2D
                this.engine.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(this.sSkates,   this.bSkates,   true, true));
                this.engine.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(this.sLegs,   this.bLegs,   true, true));

                // --SNIPPED--         

                // Create joints
                RevoluteJointDef jAnkle = new RevoluteJointDef();
                System.out.println("aoeu aoeu aoeu aoeu");
                this.jAnkle.initialize(bSkates, bLegs, new Vector2(stickmanPos.x, sSkates.getHeight()));
                this.jAnkle.enableMotor = true;
                this.jAnkle.motorSpeed = this.dex;
                this.jAnkle.maxMotorTorque = this.str;

        }

        ////////////////       
        // Fields
        private Testgame game;
        private PhysicsWorld engine;
        private Vector2 stickmanPos;

        // Config
        private float skatesToLegs   = 1;
        private float legsToThigh  = 1;
        private float thighToTorso = 1;
        private float torsoToHead  = 1;
        private float torsoToArms  = 1;

        // Stats
        private float gli = 0;  // Higher number = lower skate friction
        private float str = 0;  // Joint torque
        private float dex = 0;  // Joint speed
        private float con = 0;  // Impact tolerance

        // JointPositions
        private float shoulderPos;
        private float neckPos;
        private float hipPos;
        private float kneePos;

        protected BitmapTextureAtlas  textureAtlas;

        protected ITiledTextureRegion tSkates;
        protected ITiledTextureRegion tLegs;
        // --SNIPPED--

        protected AnimatedSprite sSkates;
        protected AnimatedSprite sLegs;
        // --SNIPPED--

        protected Body bSkates;
        protected Body bLegs;
        // --SNIPPED-- 

        protected RevoluteJointDef jAnkle;
        // --SNIPPED-- 
}
```

Hopefully it's not something obviously stupid that I've done. If it is, please forgive me.

Comment: I can see that you're shadowing the jAnkle variable, but I can't see how that is causing your NPE to be thrown.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels What do you mean by shadowing

Comment: Maybe stickman object is null

Comment: You've declared the variable in the *class* here `protected RevoluteJointDef jAnkle;`, and yet re-declare it in the constructor.

Comment: @JunedAhsan: ???? this is the Stickman constructor.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Actually, that was what was causing the issue, thanks for spotting! Put it as an answer, and i'll Accept. Sorry about the forewarned 'obviously stupid' :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be shadowing several variables including your sSkates, bSkates, jAnkle variables. This is where you declare the variables both in the class and once again in a constructor, method or other local block. I don't see how this is causing your NPE **within** the constructor, but it is a common cause of NPE's elsewhere.

Comment: This was the cause of the problem. Only the jAnkle localized to the constructor was given a properly instanced object, and the one in use further down the code was left Null. Removed the superfluous `RevoluteJointDef` in the constructor, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: @Jarmund: what confused me about your question is that you localized the NPE as being thrown *from within the constructor*, which doesn't make sense. It should be thrown outside of the constructor with this type of error.

Comment: My guess is that it happened because i tend to overuse the `this` keyword, and I would think that made it operate on the jAnkle field in the class, and not bother with the constructor localized equivalent.